# .Net - C#: Entity Framework Querys complejos

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, .net, sql, entity-framework

saludos a todos.

Estoy empezando a estudiar Entity Framework y me han surgido un par de dudas:

Con el enfoque tradicional de ADO.Net puedo crear consultas o querys complejos, es decir, que haga uso de INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, de funciones como MAX(), SUM(), GROUP BY, ORDER BY y haga uso de varias tablas y en el SELECT traiga campos especificos o querys dinamicos si se envia o no un parametro, haciendo uso de strings, de AddParameters y posteriormente haciendo el ExecuteQuery().
Como podria lograr lo mismo con Entity Framework ?

Un ejemplo de un query seria:

```
SELECT ic_clie.cclie, ic_clie.cclex, ic_clie.nombr, ic_dire.telef AS contacto, ic_prod.cprod, ic_prod.cprex,  ic_prod.nombr, atr01.nombr AS atr01_nombr, atr02.nombr AS atr02_nombr, atr03.nombr AS atr03_nombr, atr04.nombr AS atr04_nombr, 
atr05.nombr AS atr05_nombr, atr06.nombr AS atr06_nombr, atr07.nombr AS atr07_nombr, atr08.nombr AS atr08_nombr, 
atr09.nombr AS atr09_nombr, atr10.nombr AS atr10_nombr, sum(ic_pedd.cannd) AS cannd, ic_inve.canti ,ic_prod.unmev, SUM(ic_pedd.cannd*ic_pedd.precu) AS ValorPedido, imone.cmone,im_mone.cemon 
FROM ic_pedc
            INNER JOIN ic_pedd ON ic_pedd.cempr= ic_pedc.cempr AND ic_pedd.cpedi = ic_pedc.cpedi 
            INNER JOIN ic_clie ON ic_clie.cempr= ic_pedc.cempr AND ic_clie.cclie = ic_pedc.cclie 
            INNER JOIN ic_prod ON ic_prod.cempr= ic_pedd.cempr AND  ic_prod.cprod = ic_pedd.cprod 
            INNER JOIN ic_inve ON ic_inve.cempr= ic_pedd.cempr AND  ic_inve.cprod = ic_pedd.cprod 
            INNER JOIN ic_dire ON ic_dire.cclie = ic_clie.cclie AND ic_dire.princ = 'S' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr01 ON atr01.catri = 1 AND atr01.ccatv = ic_prod.atr01 AND atr01.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr02 ON atr02.catri = 2 AND atr02.ccatv = ic_prod.atr02 AND atr02.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr03 ON atr03.catri = 3 AND atr03.ccatv = ic_prod.atr03 AND atr03.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr04 ON atr04.catri = 4 AND atr04.ccatv = ic_prod.atr04 AND atr04.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr05 ON atr05.catri = 5 AND atr05.ccatv = ic_prod.atr05 AND atr05.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr06 ON atr06.catri = 6 AND atr06.ccatv = ic_prod.atr06 AND atr06.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr07 ON atr07.catri = 7 AND atr07.ccatv = ic_prod.atr07 AND atr07.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr08 ON atr08.catri = 8 AND atr08.ccatv = ic_prod.atr08 AND atr08.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr09 ON atr09.catri = 9 AND atr09.ccatv = ic_prod.atr09 AND atr09.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN ic_atrv AS atr10 on atr10.catri = 10 AND atr10.ccatv = ic_prod.atr10 AND atr10.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' 
            LEFT JOIN im_mone ON im_mone.cmone = ic_pedc.cmone 
WHERE ic_pedd.cannd > 0 AND ic_pedc.cempr = 'PARAMETRO' AND ic_pedc.estad >= 2 AND DATE(ic_pedc.fecho) >= PARAMETRO_FECHA' AND DATE(ic_pedc.fecho) <= 'PARAMETRO_FECHA' AND ic_prod.cprex = 'PARAMETRO' 
GROUP BY ic_clie.cclie, ic_prod.cprod, ic_prod.cprex;
```

El anterior query podria implementarlo facilmente en un metodo en mi DAL, haciendo uso de if(parametros) para que evalue si se debe agregar un parametro de busqueda y asi volverlo dinamico. Pero como podria hacer lo mismo con EF ?

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando tienes queries bien complejas y son del tipo "ReadOnly", te sugiero crear una Vista en el SQL Server y usarlas al mismo estilo de las tablas con EF. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx Pero eso no significaria que cada vez que necesite una consulta compleja deba crear una Vista para posteriormente usarla con EF ? Y si mi proyecto tiene muchas consultas complejas podria entonces llenarme de Vistas. O me equivoco ?

Comment: Como bien dice el colega @fredyfx, lo mejor sería utilizar vistas. Yo, en lo personal cuando una query comprende más de dos tablas, creo un procedimiento almacenado y lo llamo desde C#; es algo mucho más eficiente trabajar con eso directamente desde tu IDE de BD a crear una consulta muy compleja en tu código

Comment: Si el proyecto tiene muchas consultas complejas... habría que analizar detenidamente por qué existen, podrías darle una mejora de diseño a nivel de BD, o también crear procedimientos almacenados/vistas, que andar haciendo varias queries complejas en EF te va a costar buena cantidad de recursos a menos que las ejecutes como RAW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096793/3613462

Comment: Gracias.  Es sobre un proyecto que ya esta implementado pero que se busca mejorar y optimizar, en cuanto a las consultas grandes, digamos que en este momento son necesarias, si el proyecto tiene cierta cantidad de este tipo de consultas es igual de recomendable el uso de EF ? Para este tipo de consultas entonces hacer uso de Stored Procedure o Vistas, ya que digamos que la mitad del proyecto contiene querys complejas y el objetivo es como ya dije, mejorar y optimizar.